# How would pretty be classified in this sentence

Tags: adjectives, adverbs, parts-of-speech

The sentence is "You look pretty tonight". I believe that pretty would be an adjective as it's referring to "You".

However in the sentence "You look pretty gorgeous tonight" I believe that pretty would be an adverb.

In the first sentence is pretty saying how "You" looks though, meaning it would be an adverb?

Comment: Use the test. Replace the word with something that's undeniably an adverb, then replace it with something that's clearly an adjective. See which one sounds right to you. Is it "you look great tonight", or is it "you look greatly tonight"? There you go. Simple as that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the sentence,

> You look pretty tonight

Pretty serves as an adjective and "look" serves more of the function of linking verb than action verb.

In the second sentence,

> You look pretty gorgeous tonight.

Pretty does indeed serve as an *adverb* modifying the *adjective* gorgeous.

You have made some interesting observations here.  The verb "look" is a linking verb here like "to be" instead of describing an action.

Comment: I don't think you meant to say that pretty serves as a "verb" did you?

Comment: Thanks @WS2!!!!  I meant adverb.  I changed it.